# How to return newly formated String in one line?

Tags: java, return, string-formatting

I have to make a method in Java that gets some integers and strings and then returns a single String. But I only know how to print out all together, like this for example:

```
public void toString(int num, String text){
    System.out.print(num + " " + text);
}
```

But I'm wondering how can I do it with `return`?
Somethig like this?

```
public String toString(int num, String text){
    return (num + " " + text);
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to cast the `int` into a `String` before returning it as a `String`.

```
public String toString(int num, String text) {
    return Integer.toString(num) + " " + text;
}
```